# How to display very big list in select option

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch the value from database and display it in select option in edit form.
this is my code

```
<select class="form-select" id="type" name="station_name" required data-error="Station Required"> 
   <option value="" disabled>Station</option>
      <?php foreach ($stations as $station) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $station['station_name'] ?>" <?php if($station['station_name']== $row['station_name']){ echo 'selected'; }?>><?php echo $station['station_name']; ?>  </option>
  <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

the above code fetching stations from downtime table .It is working .But the downtime table contains large amount of data .So edit form is loading for long time .How to reduce the loading time?
I have tried ajax select
below is my code

```
$("#station_name").select2({
                ajax: {
                    url: "getstation.php",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            line:line,
                            searchTerm: params.term // search term
                        };
                    },
                   processResults: function (response) {
                      
                                  return {
                         //  results: $.map(response, function(obj) {
                            results: response
                             //alert(response);
                              //return { id: obj.id, text: obj.station_name };
                            // })
                       };
                        
                    },
                    cache: true
                }
              //  minimumInputLength: 1
            });
```

getting json response. but not displaying it in select option

Comment: define "large".

Comment: if it's really big, you can try live search option instead

Comment: You can try select2 and can load the data through ajax on page load to reduce the load time on the page.

Comment: I have tried using ajax select 2 . return {  results: response  }; I am getting json options response .but not displaying in options .

Comment: `$('#mySelect2').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: '/example/api',
    processResults: function (data) {
      // Transforms the top-level key of the response object from 'items' to 'results'
      return {
        results: data.items
      };
    }
  }
});`

For reference you can check https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: You could also catch though Ajax when user adds at least x characters.

Comment: tried   return {         results: data.items       };  showing no results found

Comment: use console.log and check if the data is coming in data variable and then pass the value that you are sending. Most important thing you have to send json response from the backend as it will be much easier to deal in the frontend ajax

Comment: checked .data is coming

Comment: in which format , Can you please share the code sample you are using or the link where you are trying to implement the code. It will help understanding it better

Comment: url: "getstation.php",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            line:line,
                            searchTerm: params.term // search term
                        };
                    },
                   processResults: function (response) {     
                        return {
                         
                            results: response

Comment: If you have that much data that it slows down form creation noticably, a `<select>` will be unusable for users probably anyways (Did you ever try to find a specific entry in such a big dropdown list without a filter or search?) I would suggest that you think of a different UI like search that doesn't present the user with such a huge number of options at once - this also should reduce the load time.